# Convert to float a String containing a floating point number formatted according to locale that uses comma for decimals

Tags: processing

Using the "processing" programming language I use for example:

```
float f=3.4;
String s=nf(f,1,2);
dest.setText(s); // the GTextField from g4p_controls thus contains "3.4" according to the locale I use.
```

Afterwards I use:

```
float f=float(dest.getText());
```

But it does not work because it does not recongize "," as the decimal separator.

What should be done ? Is not a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your issue, Processing's `float()` function seems to convert "3.4" as to `3.4` as expected:

```
import g4p_controls.*;

GTextField dest;

void setup(){
  dest = new GTextField(this,0,0,100,30);

  float f = 3.4;
  String s = nf(f,1,2);

  println("float",f,"string",s); 

  dest.setText(s);


  float fc = float(dest.getText());

  println("string",dest.getText(),"converted float",fc,"is converted float equal to origina float?",fc == f);
}

void draw(){

}
```

Comment: Do you use a locale with comma "," as the separator of integer and decimal digits instead of "." that e.g. USA locales use ?

Comment: The output of your code on my computer gives: String 3,40 is converted float NaN is converted float equal to original float ? false

Comment: your example snippet in the question doesn't mention `3,4`, mentions `3.4` which parses correctly (but you're right, `println(Float.parseFloat("3,4"));` throws a `NumberFormatException`). You can use `String.format` to use the US Locale explicitly: `String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%.2f", 3.4)`